# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 14.04

How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS?
After running software updater also, it is not getting updated.

Answer (score 15):

If your system(14.04) is updated once successfully on or after the date *July 24, 2014* your system must have 14.04.1 automatically.

If you didn't, Do the following,

Open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

1) To update type following command in terminal,

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

2) To check it type following command in terminal,

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

You will get result as,

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update do not update packages , it just update package list

Comment: @Tachyons sorry I forget to add the installation command,now updated, thank you..

Answer (score 5):

Point releases are just security updates up to date...if you keep your Ubuntu 14.04 install updated you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: 14.04.1 disables all dash scopes by default, including Amazon, so it may be worthwhile to get this update for some people.